# Ordering character values while preserving number order

Tags: r, alphabetical

I have a character vector like the following:

```
char <- c("C.1", "C.3", "C.10", "A.5", "D.4", "A.50", "A.49")
```

I want to sort them in alphabetical order, but if I do

```
char[order(char)]
```

I get

```
[1] "A.49" "A.5"  "A.50" "C.1"  "C.10" "C.3"  "D.4"
```

However, the desired output is `A.5, A.49, A.50, C.1, C.3, C.10, D.4` as I would like to preserve the order of the actual numbers themselves.

How can I reorder `char` like this?

Comment: Look at `gtools::mixedsort`. Pretty sure this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this.  Here is one example using `stringr`. I extract the letter and feed that in as the first argument to `order`, next I extract the digit and use that as the second argument to `order`.

```
library(stringr)
char[order(str_extract(char,"\\w"), strtoi(str_extract(char,"\\d+")))]
# [1] "A.5"  "A.49" "A.50" "C.1"  "C.3"  "C.10" "D.4"
```